# alert dialogue box in android showing error

Tags: android

hello friends i am new to android , an i want to show an alert box in my app . I have done this

```
Button butalert=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1alert);  
butalert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
           alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("vaibhav");
           alertDialogBuilder.create();
           alertDialogBuilder.show();
        }           
});
```

But I am getting error like this

```
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@410246f8 is not valid; is your activity running?
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.kaldarshika.FisrtActivity$5.onClick(FisrtActivity.java:473)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-17 15:36:13.556: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

with

```
alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Comment: try to use yourActivityName.this instead of context

Comment: try this context = this

Comment: Is this code written inside an Activity or Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

change`context` to `YourActivity.this`

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("vaibhav");
 alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `context` in 
`AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);`
properly set?

If so, you can try by doing :

`AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("vaibhav");
    AlertDialog aDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    aDialog.show();`

Comment: i have set final Context context = this; in my aplication

Comment: Set Context = this in your activity page